# clearing heap memory of running process c++

Tags: c++, linux, heap-memory

I have process that is running continuously. it allocates some memory dynamically and heap size increases. for example, 20 MB heap memory is allocated (checked in /proc/pid/smaps). After some condition is true, the dynamically allocated memory needs to be cleared and free/delete operators are called, BUT the process still runs (continuously).

```
class Object 
{
   vector <Object1> OB1;
   vector <Object2> OB2;
   //etc
 }

class Object1 {
  vector<string> temp2;
  vector<string> temp1;
  //etc 
}
//similar for Object2


std::vector <Object *> List;

Object* temp;
temp = new Object;

//Work with Object and its members (also vectors inside) (so object Size increases accordingly as vector size increases.

//insert into vector  
List.push_back(temp);

//Now clear function  
freeFunc()
  int i;
  int size = List.size();
  if (size == 0)
     return;

  for (i = 0; i < size; i ++)
  {
     delete List[i];
      List[i] = NULL;
  }
  List.clear();
  vector <Object *>().swap(List); //swap with empty vector
}
```

Will the heap memory be cleared for this running process ? OR it will be release ONLY if process is made to stop?
I am doubting the code (freeFunc()) is not freeing the memory after the condition is met. The process cannot be killed or made to stop.

Comment: Freed/deleted nonsmall chunks of memory go back to the system. You  don't need to suspend or kill the process. In any case, you should  use RAII rather than raw pointers for memory management in C++.

Answer (score 2):

If memory will actually be released to the OS is entirely dependent on your environment/OS and underlying implementation of malloc.

For example there is no point to releasing memory if the block is small and it can be reused. 
However in general you can assume it will be.

Now about your code, I would refactor it to use:

```
vector <unique_ptr<Object>> objects;
```

and to release it and free all your objects you can just call:

```
objects.clear();
```

Comment: the block is comparatively large (about 100MB+).

Comment: then it will probably be released back. The suggestion not to use naked new/delete stills tand